# Validate UITextField with Regex in Xamarin.ios

Tags: regex, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to validate a `UITextField` in Xamarin.iOS by using a regex to match only numbers, and the `.` and `-` characters. How can I achieve this?

I have tried with the following solution but it doesn't match:

```cs
if (System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.IsMatch("string", "pattern"))
```

Comment: What hav eyou tried? SO is not a coding service. You have to show some effort on your side

Comment: I have tried with the following solution: if(System.Text.RegularExpression.Regex.IsMatch("string", "pattern")) but not matches properly

Comment: you're passing `"pattern"` as a literal string? can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Also, its better to edit your question and add code than to post a comment with code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like more of a regex issue, have you tried this?:

```
bool notValid = Regex.IsMatch (textField.Text, "[^0-9.-]")
```

If you are stuck with Regex issue I would highly recoomend this [site](https://regex101.com/)